# Access strimzi kafka externally using tls authentication

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, strimzi

I have setup strimzi kafka on azure AKS and trying to access it from outside using TLS authentication but facing below error.We are using our own certificates and configured under listener section.

kafka yaml:

```
apiVersion: kafka.strimzi.io/v1beta2
kind: Kafka
metadata:
  name: eesb-cluster
spec:
  kafka:
    version: 3.1.0
    replicas: 3
    logging: 
      type: inline
      loggers:
        kafka.root.logger.level: "INFO"
    resources: 
      requests:
        memory: 2Gi
        cpu: "1"
      limits:
        memory: 4Gi
        cpu: "2"
    readinessProbe:
      initialDelaySeconds: 15
      timeoutSeconds: 5
      periodSeconds: 10
      successThreshold: 1
      failureThreshold: 3
    livenessProbe:
      initialDelaySeconds: 15
      timeoutSeconds: 5
      periodSeconds: 10
      successThreshold: 1
      failureThreshold: 3
    template:
      pod:
        imagePullSecrets:
        - name: artifactory-kafka
     # Kafka JVM      
    jvmOptions:
      gcLoggingEnabled: true
      -Xms: 1g
      -Xmx: 2g
      -XX:
        UseG1GC: true
        MaxGCPauseMillis: 20
        InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent: 35
        ExplicitGCInvokesConcurrent: true
    listeners:
      - name: plain
        port: 9092
        type: internal
        tls: false
      - name: external
    port: 9093
    type: loadbalancer
    tls: true
    authentication:
     type: tls  
    configuration:
      bootstrap:
        loadBalancerIP: 20.22.199.99
        annotations:
          external-dns.alpha.kubernetes.io/hostname: bootstrap.example.com
        alternativeNames: 
            - bootstrap.example.com  
      brokers:
      - broker: 0
        loadBalancerIP: 20.22.199.100
        annotations:
          external-dns.alpha.kubernetes.io/hostname: kafka-0.example.com
        advertisedHost: kafka-0.example.com](url)
        
      - broker: 1
        loadBalancerIP: 20.22.199.101
        annotations:
          external-dns.alpha.kubernetes.io/hostname: kafka-1.example.com
        advertisedHost: kafka-1.example.com
      - broker: 2
        loadBalancerIP: 20.22.199.102
        annotations:
          external-dns.alpha.kubernetes.io/hostname: kafka-2.example.com
        advertisedHost: kafka-2.example.com
    
      brokerCertChainAndKey:
        secretName: source-kafka-listener-cert
        certificate: tls.crt
        key: tls.key 
    config:
      num.partitions: 1
      offsets.topic.replication.factor: 3
      log.retention.hours: 24
      log.segment.bytes: 1073741824
      log.retention.check.interval.ms: 300000
      num.network.threads: 3
      num.io.threads: 8
      transaction.state.log.replication.factor: 3
      transaction.state.log.min.isr: 2
      default.replication.factor: 3
      min.insync.replicas: 2
      num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir: 1
      inter.broker.protocol.version: "3.1"
      auto.create.topics.enable: false
      delete.topic.enable: true
    # Rack awareness
     # replica.selector.class: org.apache.kafka.common.replica.RackAwareReplicaSelector 
     # broker.rack:
    #rack:
     # topologyKey: topology.kubernetes.io/region=
     # topologyKey: topology.kubernetes.io/zone= 
    storage:
      type: jbod
      volumes:
      - deleteClaim: false
        id: 0
        size: 80Gi
        type: persistent-claim
      
    # Kafka Prometheus JMX Exporter
    #metricsConfig:
      #type: jmxPrometheusExporter
      #valueFrom:
        #configMapKeyRef:
          #key: kafka-metrics-config.yml
          #name: kafka-zk-metrics
    #metrics:
      #lowercaseOutputName: true
    #kafkaExporter:
      #groupRegex: .*
      #topicRegex: .*
    # Kafka JMX metrics
    #jmxOptions:
      #authentication:
        #type: "password"
  
    
  zookeeper:
    replicas: 3
    storage:
      type: persistent-claim
      size: 10Gi
      deleteClaim: false
    # Zookeeper loggers and log level  
    #logging:
      #type: external
      #name: kafka-logging-configmap
    logging: 
      type: inline
      loggers:
        zookeeper.root.logger: "INFO"
    resources:
      requests:
        memory: 1Gi
        cpu: "1"
      limits:
        memory: 2Gi
        cpu: "2"
    # Zookeeper JVM      
    jvmOptions:
      gcLoggingEnabled: true
      -Xms: 1g
      -Xmx: 1g
      -XX:
        UseG1GC: true
        MaxGCPauseMillis: 20
        InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent: 35
        ExplicitGCInvokesConcurrent: true
```

I have setup same kafka cert in authentication section of kafka connect and added all the CA certicate in truststore on the client side.

Kafka connect client yaml:

```
apiVersion: kafka.strimzi.io/v1beta2
kind: KafkaConnect
metadata:
  name: eesb-connect-cluster
  annotations:
    strimzi.io/use-connector-resources: "true"
spec:
  version: 3.1.0
  replicas: 2
  image: packages.alm.eurofins.com/docker-eurofins-eesb-prerelease/com/eurofins/eesb/eesb-kafka-connect:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
  bootstrapServers: itaag108-uat2.eesb.eurofins.com:9093
  authentication:
    type: tls
    certificateAndKey:
      certificate: tls.crt
      key: tls.key
      secretName: source-kafka-listener-cert
  tls:
    trustedCertificates:
      - certificate: ca1.crt
        secretName: source-kafka-trust-cert
      - certificate: ca2.crt
        secretName: source-kafka-trust-cert
      - certificate: ca3.crt
        secretName: source-kafka-trust-cert
  config:
    key.converter: org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
    value.converter: org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
    key.converter.schemas.enable: true
    value.converter.schemas.enable: true
    offset.flush.timeout.ms: 120000
    offset.flush.interval.ms: 10000
    group.id: connect-cluster
    offset.storage.topic: connect-cluster-offsets
    config.storage.topic: connect-cluster-configs
    status.storage.topic: connect-cluster-status
    # -1 means it will use the default replication factor configured in the broker
    config.storage.replication.factor: 2
    offset.storage.replication.factor: 2
    status.storage.replication.factor: 2
    config.providers: file
    config.providers.file.class: org.apache.kafka.common.config.provider.FileConfigProvider
  resources:
    requests:
      cpu: "1"
      memory: 512m
    limits:
      cpu: "2"
      memory: 2Gi
  logging:
    type: inline
    loggers:
      log4j.rootLogger: "INFO"
  readinessProbe:
    initialDelaySeconds: 60
    periodSeconds: 20
    timeoutSeconds: 30
  livenessProbe:
    initialDelaySeconds: 60
    periodSeconds: 20
    timeoutSeconds: 30
  template:
      pod:
        imagePullSecrets:
        - name: artifactory-kafka
  externalConfiguration:
    volumes:
      - name: connector-config
        secret:
          secretName: target-uat-db-auth      
  jvmOptions:
    gcLoggingEnabled: false
    -Xmx: 1024m
    -Xms: 512m
    -XX:
        UseG1GC: true
        MaxGCPauseMillis: 20
        InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent: 35
        ExplicitGCInvokesConcurrent: true
        UseStringDeduplication: true
```

I have not made any changes to cluster-ca-cert or clients-ca-cert automatically generated by strimzi.

```
Error:
2022-09-13 09:39:34,227 WARN [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Metadata update failed due to authentication error

org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.internals.AdminMetadataManager) [kafka-admin-client-thread | adminclient-1]

 org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SslAuthenticationExceptio 
n: Failed to process post-handshake messages
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Tag mismatch!
```

please help on this issue.

Thanks,
Shiva

Comment: You should ideally share the full Kafka CRs. But looking at least at your snippets, they seem to be unaligned parts which is not clear if it is just copy-paste error or an actual issues. You have also TLS authentication enabled on the Kafka CR listener. But your Kafka Connect snippet does not have any authentication section. Again, it is not clear if it is missing completelyor you just didn't copy pasted it.

Comment: @Jakub - I have updated my query. please ignore allignment it is copy past error.I am using same certificate at the broker  and kafka connect .